# Azure Event Hub Connection when creating Event Hub Trigger with function app in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-eventhub

I am trying to provision a function inside azure function app using terraform and using event hub trigger as the function trigger.

this is the sample code for function_app that I am provisioning

```
  resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example-linux-serviceplan" {
      name                = "linux-service-plan"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.azure-xxxxx.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.azure-xxxxxx.location
      os_type             = "Linux"
      sku_name            = "S1"
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example-linux-app" {
      name                = "example-linux-app"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.azure-xxxxx.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.azure-xxxxxx.location
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example-linux-serviceplan.id
    
      storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.azure-xxxxx.name
      storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.azure-xxxxx.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "connection_name" = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.azure-xxxx.default_primary_connection_string
  }
    
      site_config {
        application_stack {
          node_version = "18"
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "example" {
          name            = "example-function-app-function"
          function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.example-linux-app.id
          test_data = jsonencode({
            "name" = "Azure"
          })
          config_json = jsonencode({
            "bindings" = [
              {
                "authLevel" = "function"
                "direction" = "in"
                "name"       = "req"
                "type"       = "eventHubTrigger"
                "connection" = "connection_name"
              },
            ]
          })
        }
```

I also tried with binding as below

```
  config_json = jsonencode({
"bindings" : [
  {
    "name" : "eventHubMessages",
    "type" : "eventHubTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "eventHubName" : azurerm_eventhub.azure-xxxx.name,
    "connection" : azurerm_eventhub_namespace.azure-xxxxx.default_primary_connection_string,
    "cardinality" : "many",
    "dataType" : "",
    "consumerGroup" : "$Default"
  }
],
"disabled" : false
```

})

However as in below screenshot, still this event hub connection is not created, and I could not find any terraform resource that creates the `Event Hub Connection`

[image: Screeshot of trigger in portal]

Is there a way to to create this event hub connection from terraform ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the **connection string** name. Make sure that the connection string key in `app_settings` block matches with the `config_json` connection name value.

```bash
 app_settings = {
    "connectionjahn" = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.default_primary_connection_string
  }
```

```bash
config_json = jsonencode({
            "bindings" = [
              {
                "authLevel" = "function"
                "direction" = "in"
                "name"       = "req"
                "type"       = "eventHubTrigger"
                "connection" = "connectionjahn"
              }
            ]
          })
```

***Note***: The connection name `"connectionjahn"` remains consistent in both of the above provided code snippets. Modify in your code accordingly.

***Complete terraform code is given below:***

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxx"
  }
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "functionsapptejstsa"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
 resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example-linux-serviceplan" {
      name                = "linux-service-planj"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      os_type             = "Linux"
      sku_name            = "S1"
    }
 resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
    name                = "examplejanamespace"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    sku                 = "Standard"
    capacity            = 2
 }
 
 resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "example-linux-app" {
      name                = "example-linux-appja"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example-linux-serviceplan.id
      storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
 
  app_settings = {
    "connectionjahn" = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.default_primary_connection_string
  }
      site_config {
        application_stack {
          python_version = "3.11"
        }
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "example" {
          name            = "example-function-apjahfunction"
          function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.example-linux-app.id
          language        = "Python"
          test_data = jsonencode({
            "name" = "Azure"
          })
          config_json = jsonencode({
            "bindings" = [
              {
                "authLevel" = "function"
                "direction" = "in"
                "name"       = "req"
                "type"       = "eventHubTrigger"
                "connection" = "connectionjahn"
              }
            ]
          })
        }
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]